# how to get path in url using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not very good with regex

I want a regex expression that matches these:

```
http://localhost:3000/categories/football
http://localhost:3000/categories/football/2222/45444
http://localhost:3000/categories/tennis/45454
http://localhost:3000/categories/football/12
http://localhost:3000/categories/cricket/
```

basically, for all the above potential URL paths, I want the words after `categories/` and before the second `/` to be returned

i.e.

football, football, tennis, football, cricket

I got this far:
`(categories)/\w+`

but obviously, that still includes categories

Comment: just use a group for the `\w+` part. You will get the content with `$2`

Comment: `var categories = location.pathname.split("/")[2];`

Comment: I would just go for splitting on the slash instead. `const [ protocol, host, page, topic, id, reference ] = route.replace( '://', '/' ).split( '/' ); return topic;`

Comment: @mplungjan or `location.pathname.split('categories')[1].split('/')[1];` just incase there are random other things before categories

Comment: @AndrewBone I was considering that, but then a regex is more readable

Comment: @mplungjan things you never expect to read, "regex is more readable" 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the capturing group from `(categories)` to `(\w+)` and use a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert that what followes is an optional `(?=\/?)` forward slash.

The values you are looking for are in captured group 1.

[`categories\/(\w+)(?=\/?)`](https://regex101.com/r/ozEjO4/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "http://localhost:3000/categories/football",
  "http://localhost:3000/categories/football/2222/45444",
  "http://localhost:3000/categories/tennis/45454",
  "http://localhost:3000/categories/football/12",
  "http://localhost:3000/categories/cricket/"
];
let pattern = /categories\/(\w+)(?=\/?)/;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.match(pattern)[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just split - if the category is the second in the pathname always

```js
var loc = "/categories/football/2222/45444"; // var loc = location.pathname
console.log(loc.split("/")[2])
```

Comment: I would prefer this answer

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```js
var url1 = "http://localhost:3000/categories/football"
var url2 = "http://localhost:3000/categories/football/2222/45444"
var url3 = "http://localhost:3000/categories/tennis/45454"
var url4 = "http://localhost:3000/categories/football/12"
var url5 = "http://localhost:3000/categories/cricket/"

var regex = /categories\/(\w+)(?=\/?)/;
console.log(regex.exec(url1)[1]);
console.log(regex.exec(url2)[1]);
console.log(regex.exec(url3)[1]);
console.log(regex.exec(url4)[1]);
console.log(regex.exec(url5)[1]);
```

Comment: That's the same as an answer from a few minutes ago 

Comment: while i was typing the answer someone has posted the same :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RegEx [`(?<=categories\/)[^\/\n]+`](https://regex101.com/r/uQCaDA/1/)

- `(?<=categories\/)` makes sure your match is preceded by `categories/`
- `[^\/\n]+` matches anything but a `/` or a `newline` 1 or more times

[**Demo at Regex101.**](https://regex101.com/r/uQCaDA/1/)

```js
var re =  /(?<=categories\/)[^\/\n]+/
console.log(
"http://localhost:3000/categories/football/2222/45444".match(re)[0]
)
```

Comment: This will only work in Chrome until EchmaScript 2018 is implemented in for example Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude categories from your capture group

```
let regex = /(?:categories)+(\/\w+)/;
urls.forEach((str) => {
  console.log(str.match(regex)[1].replace('/',''));
});
```